# Bisecting any polygonal shape in $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, geometry

I am currently reading the following theorem from munkres which I understand.

Thm:

Given any two bounded polygonal regions in $\mathbb{R^2}$, there exists a line in $\mathbb{R^2}$ that bisects each of them.

Munkres mentions that we can do it for any bounded polygonal shape in $\mathbb{R^2}$. 
Here is his reasoning: "Simply take the horizontal line $y = c$, let $f(c)$ 
denote the area of that part of $A$ that lies beneat this line, note that $f$ is continuous function of $c$, and use intermediate-value theorem to find a value of $c$ for which $f(c)$ equals exactly half of area of $A$", but here we have that it will be a function in bounded region in $\mathbb{R^2}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, so how come can we just use IVT here ? Is there some generalization of the IVT theorem ?

Comment: how many different polygonal regions are being simultaneously bisected?

Comment: Actually, you have a function from $R$ to $R$, not from $R^2$ to $R$.

Comment: Your Thm as stated is simply false.

Comment: I adjusted it thank you.

Comment: The procedure described by Munkres is for bisecting one region, not two.

Comment: Check the bisection theorem @TonyK

Comment: If I google "bisection theorem" I get nothing relevant. And I don't like repeating myself, but your last paragraph has nothing to do with the simultaneous bisection of two regions (which is what your Thm is about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any real number $c$, you are asked to consider the horizontal line $y = c$, and consider how much of the polygon's area lies below this line, which is the value $f(c)$.  The domain of this function is not the polygon, but the set of possible values of $c$, which is $\mathbb{R}$.  So $f$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and the IVT applies.

Comment: Alright I see but the interval then is unbounded or do we consider the lines that start at the top of the polygon ? @MartianInvader

Comment: @l33ter if you look earlier in the book the intermediate value theorem is proved for more general spaces.

Comment: I see okay I get it now @MattSamuel